# How Can I upgrade my python3 version from 3.5.2 to 3.7 in AWS EC2 ubuntu instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

How Can I upgrade my python3 version from 3.5.2 to 3.7 in AWS EC2 ubuntu instance?

i am getting **ImportError: No module named 'secrets'** error while trying to runserver using command *python3 manage.py runserver*. I read somewhere that secrets are not supported in python3 version 3.5, and it works for only higher versions. My python version is 3.5.2. I want to upgrade the version.

I tried **sudo apt-get install python3.7**, but its not working:

```
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package python3.7 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7'
```

Then I tried **sudo update-alternatives --config python3**, this is also not working

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

first do this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Then

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa 
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

reference : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libpq-dev libssl-dev openssl libffi-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3.7-dev
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

In case you don't have the repository and so it fires a not-found package you first have to install this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: same answer. Upvoting this.

Comment: Commands ran successfully but unfortunately the python version has not changed. It still 3.5.2

Comment: sudo apt-get remove python3

Comment: Remove python3 previous version first then execute these commands

Comment: Which python version it's showing now, after running this command"sudo apt-get remove python3"

Comment: Try to remove previous version of python using these commands:

sudo apt uninstall python3
, 
sudo apt-get remove 'python3.*'